# Cannot convert string to uint in c#

Tags: c#, uint

i am pretty new to c# and for some reason my number wont convert for the life of me. My code is:

```
foreach(var descriptionid in test.items)
{
    ulong description = Convert.ToUInt32(descriptionid.Value.descriptionid);
    Console.WriteLine(description);
}
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Edit: This is the error message: http://gyazo.com/ed87941f4c8226ad6ebfd60879a5f173

Comment: Whats the problem and error message?

Comment: Noo, its already a string and I need to convert it to a uint

Comment: Name your variables according to their functionality. Anyway, `descriptionid.Value.descriptionid` is really not a good practice. About your question: debug it, step into a foreach loop and learn what is this value equal to when it breaks. Btw, long is a Int64 not an Int32.

Comment: @ETurns, What's the descriptionId, I can not understand descriptionid.Value.descriptionid?????

Comment: @ETurns - for persistence? Like, for storing in a database or...

Comment: @DoKZ this is what i get: http://gyazo.com/0c44c4bfb238e59930569299ba9e63f9

Comment: @wahwahwah its so that I can call my get description function. It requires the descriptionid but as a ulong, not a string

Comment: I edited the post to include the errormessage

Comment: @ETurns, descriptionid.Value.descriptionid = "310776840_0", ofcourse you can not convert it to long or any other digit type.

Comment: @ETurns, you can split by '_' and use the first part, check my answer

Comment: Is the "310776840_0" _0 supposed to be a decimal point ?
In that case you should replace it with your decimal separator and try your convert again

Comment: @OddmarDam no its supposed to be an underscore. Its a weird way that the bot works to store the descriptions. Im just recoding it for my purposes, thankfully these guys helped me fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fisrt of all you need to get rid of the "_0" that exist at the end of the number, like that:

```
string number =  descriptionid.Value.descriptionid.ToString();
string[] nums = number.Split ('_');
```

And than to write the following code:

```
 ulong description = Convert.ToUInt64(nums[0]);
```

Comment: System.Convert does not contain a definition for 'ToiUlong'

Comment: What is the value inser Value.descriptionId, please give me an example of one

Comment: Well, because of the _ it can't parse the string to a number (int\long etc). you need to get rid of the _0, i'll add it to the answer

Comment: Got it, here is the solution

Comment: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'split' and no extension method 'split' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Haa...Split with Capital S

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your problem and error (whats descriptionid.Value.descriptionid ?????), but you can change your code like this:

```
foreach(var descriptionid in test.items)
{
    //var description = Convert.ToUInt64(descriptionid.Value.descriptionid);
    var description = Convert.ToUInt64(descriptionid.Value.descriptionid.Split(new char[]{'_'})[0]);

    Console.WriteLine(description);
}
```

Comment: I updated the post to include a screenshot of the error!